# cubic polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

I need to find closed-form solutions of the polynomial
$$
y^3-\alpha_6 y^2+(\alpha_1-\alpha_2)y-(\alpha_3+\alpha_4-\alpha_5)=0,
$$
where all the coefficients are real numbers. I'm worried that the solutions are huge ugly expressions.

Comment: Your worry is not unfounded.

Comment: Yes, they are ugly. Start with Cardano's formula for $y^3+ay^2+by+c=0$ and replace $a,b,c$ by your even more complicated expressions. It's a pity that there is nothing known about any relation between $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_6$.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should not use closed form solution for this kind of equation. You should use coefficient matching like the following, construct the equations and solve it! Though there are many other ways to slice this lemon (e.g. - geometrically)

The cubic equation has 3 roots, say -  $a, b, c$. Hence the equation now can be expressed as $(y-a)(y-b)(y-c) = 0$. Then you simplify the equation, and do the coefficient matching. For example, the constant term in this equation is $abc$ which should equal to $(\alpha_3 +\alpha_4 - \alpha_5)$. And so on.

If you are hell bent on finding the closed form, [click here!](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicFormula.html)

On side note - There does not exist any closed form solution for order greater than 4! You can read about Henry Abel - who proved that!